# Mailchimp 6.x-2.6 module wont update user changes to Mailchimp

Tags: 6, emails

I am using the [MailChimp](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailchimp) module and getting a problem when updating user settings.

The new settings are not synchronized with Mailchimp. The module is only working when users are created.

In module settings I tried with sync during cron and without it.It does not sync the changes.